# Attempting to change webpack-dev-server host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-rails, webpacker

When trying to change the host in webpack-dev-server from `0.0.0.0` to `localhost`.

I looked in the code (`bin/web-pack-dev-server` generated for Rails 5.1.3), tried to understand it, and noticed what I thought was a `--host` parameter

```
PORT=8080 bin/webpack-dev-server --host=localhost
```

the `--host=localhost` flag won't work.

From `bin/web-pack-dev-server`:

```
begin
  dev_server = YAML.load_file(CONFIG_FILE)["development"]["dev_server"]

  DEV_SERVER_HOST = "http#{"s" if args('--https') ||     dev_server["https"]}://#{args('--host') || dev_server["host"]}:#{args('--port')     || dev_server["port"]}"
  puts DEV_SERVER_HOST
rescue Errno::ENOENT, NoMethodError
  puts "Webpack dev_server configuration not found in #{CONFIG_FILE}."
  puts "Please run bundle exec rails webpacker:install to install webpacker"
  exit!
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `PORT=8080 bin/webpack-dev-server --host=localhost` to `PORT=8080 bin/webpack-dev-server --host localhost`

Simply removing the `=` fixed it.